# Terminal: Jump to directory found with find

Tags: command-line

This seems like an obvious question to me but I can't find the answer... Presume I want to find a certain txt-file in my project and in Terminal I type:

`find -name test.txt`

As result I might get something like:

`./directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/test.txt`

How do I jump to `directory4` without having to type the complete path?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use bash's history support to do this. After any command, you can reference it again with `!!`:

```
[jk@pecola tmp]$ find . -name test.text
./directory1/directory2/directory3/test.text
```

To perform a `ls -l` on the output of the last command:

```
[jk@pecola tmp]$ ls -l $(!!)
ls -l $(find . -name test.text)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jk jk 0 Jan 23 20:49 ./directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/test.text
```

In this example, we use the `$(...)` syntax to use the output of the command as an argument to another command.

Because `!!` references the last command run, we now need to be more specific if we want to re-run the find command, since we've run `ls` since. We can use the `!<match>` syntax to re-run the last command that started with `<match>`

```
[jk@pecola tmp]$ dirname $(!find)
dirname $(find . -name test.text)
./directory1/directory2/directory3

[jk@pecola tmp]$ cd $(dirname $(!find))
cd $(dirname $(find . -name test.text))

[jk@pecola directory4]$ ls
test.text
```

I also find this handy for re-doing commands which you need sudo for:

```
[jk@pecola tmp]$ adduser newuser
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.

[jk@pecola tmp]$ sudo !!
sudo adduser newuser
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `!!` and `$(...)`. They’re surely handy! Although I'm a little surprised that's such an "easy task" is quite a hassle, I think this solution will do!

Answer (score 0):

If the terminal session is within a GUI you can select text with your mouse (**left** button) and paste the whole text at the position of the text cursor by clicking the **middle** mouse button.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the middle click (I use shift+insert instead). I prefer a keyboard only solution though.